# I can't run camshift demo in openCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I install openCV2.3.1 in VS2010. I can read image in openCV without any error. But when I run camshiftdemo from folder open/samples/cpp. It show this error.

```
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::RotatedRect __cdecl cv::CamShift(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::Rect_<int> &,class cv::TermCriteria)" (?CamShift@cv@@YA?AVRotatedRect@1@ABV_InputArray@1@AAV?$Rect_@H@1@VTermCriteria@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\pkru\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestCmean\Debug\TestCmean.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED
```

And when I comment this line **// RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift(backproj, trackWindow,
                                    TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ));** It no error.

In my another code it show error like this. This is my code for test meanshift

```
int main()
{
    // Read reference image
    cv::Mat image= cv::imread("Desert.jpg");
    if (!image.data)
        return 0; 

    // Define ROI
    cv::Mat imageROI= image(cv::Rect(110,260,35,40));
    cv::rectangle(image, cv::Rect(110,260,35,40),cv::Scalar(0,0,255));

    // Display image
    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image",image);

    // Get the Hue histogram
    int minSat=65;
    ColorHistogram hc;
    //cv::MatND colorhist= hc.getHueHistogram(imageROI,minSat);

    ObjectFinder finder;
    //finder.setHistogram(colorhist);
    finder.setThreshold(0.2f);

    // Convert to HSV space
    cv::Mat hsv;
    cv::cvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    // Split the image
    vector<cv::Mat> v;
    cv::split(hsv,v);

    // Eliminate pixels with low saturation
    cv::threshold(v[1],v[1],minSat,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::namedWindow("Saturation");
    cv::imshow("Saturation",v[1]);

    // Get back-projection of hue histogram
    int ch[1]={0};
    cv::Mat result= finder.find(hsv,0.0f,180.0f,ch,1);

    cv::namedWindow("Result Hue");
    cv::imshow("Result Hue",result);

    cv::bitwise_and(result,v[1],result);
    cv::namedWindow("Result Hue and");
    cv::imshow("Result Hue and",result);

    // Second image
    image= cv::imread("Desert.jpg");

    // Display image
    cv::namedWindow("Image 2");
    cv::imshow("Image 2",image);

    // Convert to HSV space
    cv::cvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    // Split the image
    cv::split(hsv,v);

    // Eliminate pixels with low saturation
    cv::threshold(v[1],v[1],minSat,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::namedWindow("Saturation");
    cv::imshow("Saturation",v[1]);

    // Get back-projection of hue histogram
    result= finder.find(hsv,0.0f,180.0f,ch,1);

    cv::namedWindow("Result Hue");
    cv::imshow("Result Hue",result);

    // Eliminate low stauration pixels
    cv::bitwise_and(result,v[1],result);
    cv::namedWindow("Result Hue and");
    cv::imshow("Result Hue and",result);

    // Get back-projection of hue histogram
    finder.setThreshold(-1.0f);
    result= finder.find(hsv,0.0f,180.0f,ch,1);
    cv::bitwise_and(result,v[1],result);
    cv::namedWindow("Result Hue and raw");
    cv::imshow("Result Hue and raw",result);

    cv::Rect rect(110,260,35,40);
    cv::rectangle(image, rect, cv::Scalar(0,0,255));

    cv::TermCriteria criteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER,10,0.01);
//  cout << "meanshift= " << cv::meanShift(result,rect,criteria) << endl;

    cv::rectangle(image, rect, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));

    // Display image
    cv::namedWindow("Image 2 result");
    cv::imshow("Image 2 result",image);

    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this code it show this error.

```
1>  main.cpp
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::meanShift(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::Rect_<int> &,class cv::TermCriteria)" (?meanShift@cv@@YAHABV_InputArray@1@AAV?$Rect_@H@1@VTermCriteria@1@@Z)
1>c:\users\pkru\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestCmean\Debug\TestCmean.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILE
```

Comment: On Linux: `-lopencv_video`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CamShift and meanShift methods are part of the video\tracking module so you probably forgot to link the `opencv_videoXXX.lib`

Answer (score 0):

In case of OpenCV 3.2
Add link as '-lopencv_video'